# I do not get a mcrypt functions to work in PHP 7

Tags: php

I do not get a functions below to work PHP 7:

```
/*
 * blowfish encrypt function
 * @params
 * $key
 * $plain_text
 */
function encrypt_data($key, $plain_text) {
  $plain_text = trim($plain_text);
  $iv = substr(md5($key), 0,mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_CFB));
  $c_t = mcrypt_encrypt (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $plain_text, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
  return base64_encode($c_t); 
}

/*
 * blowfish decrypt function
 * @params
 * $key
 * $c_t
 */
function decrypt_data($key, $c_t) {
  $c_t = base64_decode($c_t);
  $iv = substr(md5($key), 0,mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_CFB));
  $p_t = mcrypt_decrypt (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $c_t, MCRYPT_MODE_CFB, $iv);
  return trim($p_t);
}
```

I will get no PHP warnings.

I think this the line, `$iv = substr(md5($key), 0,mcrypt_get_iv_size (MCRYPT_BLOWFISH,MCRYPT_MODE_CFB));`, is incorrectly made.

What to do?

Comment: Note: `Mcrypt` is outdated. please use more secured crypto like, `openssl`, `libsodium`

Comment: How long is your initialization vector? Needs to be >= 8

Comment: I don't know that how long is initialization vector but I fixed the my question because I do not get php warnigs any more and get them on some other php file. However I am made my whole solution with Zend Framework 1.2. So there seams to be lot of programming to get my solution to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that you use PHP7.2?

mcrypt isn't supported anymore in PHP7.2, was deprecated in 7.1 and finally removed.

libmcrypt, on which it is based, had an abandoned upstream support since 2007! So it was time to get rid of it.

Comment: I have a PHP 7.0.22.

Comment: Here is the solutions as a links to get mcrypt to work with PHP 7.2. But later version than PHP 7.2 I am not successfully to got it to work yet:

Comment: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-php-mcrypt-extension-on-ubuntu/

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mcrypt-php-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux